# EF6 TPT Foreign Key Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Say I have this existing schema:

[image]

and have this domain mapping as follows:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");
   modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
}

public abstract class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public string Course { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
   public int SubjectId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

And I was given a scenario that I need to query on the subject via PersonId, EF will throw me an exception saying "Invalid column name 'Student_PersonId'".

I understand EF can't see the FK well and I opted to make the Person class as a Base class since there's a chance that I'll have a Teachers table in which it is a Person as well.

Note that Student table need to have its own Primary Key and let's just say the schema was design with a relationship of:

Person -> Student (One-to-Zero or One relationship)
Student -> Subject (One-to-Many relationship)

Is there a way to fix this? Also note that if it's made using Code-First, EF will ommit StudentId on Students table and I do have an existing DB anyway

Comment: Link the code instead of uploading an image please

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Pasted the code instead of having it as an Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start off by reading [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) article about TPT in entity framework. Now you don't have a *'Student is a person'* kind of relationship, and you'll have to change some things to your database for it to work.

1. Student's primary key should at the same time be the foreign key to your people table. Since student *is* a person, it has that database as its baseclass and the Student table should only contain specific properties for student. The properties by Person are inherited.
2. Person is your `abstract` base class. Every student, teacher... is a person which is why you can't have a DbSet of Student/teacher... They are persons, so `DbSet<Person>` is all you need.
3. You can't map Person to a table. If you really want TPT **every** person is also a teacher, student... A person alone shouldn't exist, so you shouldn't map it to a table. There's a reason the class is abstract, **you can't have just a person**. For example `Person p = context.Students.FirstOrDefault();` is perfectly valid code for TPT.

That being said, if you think Person can have instances of his own (so certain persons don't have a derived class) you shouldn't opt for TPT and just work with the foreign key to the person table like you do now. If you do want to use TPT you'll have to make above adjustments.

Comment: Okay, so there's no work around for this to work? Since it's an existing database and I'm afraid DBAs won't allow such changes